# Install Lubuntu on Fujitsu Futro S450 Thin Client which is using Compact Flash as HDD

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu, flash, mbr

Trying to install Lubuntu on Fujitsu Futro S450 Thin Client which is using Compact Flash as HDD.

- Installed on internal Compact Flash using Lubuntu ISO Image on USB
- Installer runs no problems
- At the End a dialog says MBR couldnt be written, I have to install MBR on CF manually
- The dialog cant be closed, seems to be a bug

How to get this running? Is there an easy way to install MBR on CF?

The CF is this one

https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001F4VQEE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Err is similar to this one

[image]

Comment: Could you copy and post the _errors as is_.